# Opening shapeless in Intellij IDEA with Scala plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I've never really managed to get Intellij IDEA to load scala projects well.

For example, I'd like to load the shapeless library: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless

After cloning the repo, I use "Import Project" in Intellij to open it. I tell it to use the SBT external model. It opens, but fails to build due to missing dependencies ("Error: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.").

If I check the Project Structure, I have 6 modules: "shapeless", "shapeless-build", "shapeless-core", "shapeless-core-build", "shapeless-examples" and (you guessed it) "shapeless-examples-build". The source folders for all of these are wrong, including a mix of "target/scala-2.10.3/src_managed/main" and others.

I can't believe that Intellij would get this so wrong unless I'm doing something wrong. The question is: what is it that I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Try to use https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea, it works way better than intellij.

Comment: There are 1300 open issues in the intellij scala/sbt plugin, it seems to me that it is getting out of control. I spent at least 30 minutes a day dealing with this crap...